# What can we do to advertise between SE sites now that we are in public beta?

Tags: discussion, advertising, site-promotion

I am understand that community ads are available only to graduated sites. However I know that I have seen Woodworking.SE ads/links on places like DIY.SE. I will have to reach out to that community to see what they did.

If community ads are not available what can we do to get the word out now *besides* just sharing links with other users and other sites?

Do I just reach out to mods in related communities and see what they would be willing to do for us? I could make some mock ads that we could do.

To clarify I want to limit the scope of this question to advertising with the SE network and not the general internet (that is a larger topic that I have ideas for). I also don't want to focus too much on the sites we could target but more what are our options once we find those targets.

Answer (score 4):

We don't get our own Community Ads **here** on this site... but we can always suggest Community Ads on any graduated site. We don't need permission from mods, we just need to create the ad, post it on **their** CPA post and then hope they support the proposed ad with some upvotes.

To help, I'll explain the different types of ads available to us:

Every site gets default hot network question ads that rotate on all of the others in the same place that Community Promotion Ads show up. All beta sites have the same ad style. It looks like this:

[image: Beta HNQ ad Sample]

Woodworking doesn't actually have a CPA on DIY's current [post](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1132/community-promotion-ads-2016) (DIY doesn't actually have any current ones). They did have one on **[last year's](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1005/community-promotion-ads-2015)** but it doesn't look like they've resubmitted it.

If you saw this ad, then you were seeing the CPA.

[image: Woodworking CPA]
<sup>note that the ad aspect ratio has changed since this ad was created to the one used in the first image</sup>

There is a third type but that's limited to Area 51 sites still trying to get through the process.

---

So, if we want to design a site ad(s), we can do that! - I won't because I have no talent in that area....

But please note, we need to be considerate about which sites we target for these ads and we **should** target them... the imagery and text should appeal to people already using that community because they have to support our ad for it to appear on their site.

Some good target site options could include these and their (crappy) example text:

- Graphic Design - Do you also like hand drawing? Visit Arts & Crafts!
- Anime - Looking for help creating your own manga? Arts & Crafts can help!

So, if you want to recommend site ads for other sites, we should set up a post for voting on them and to let people comment on what (if any) improvements they could use. Here's [M&TV's version](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1487/lets-promote-our-community) with some examples of the targeted advertising. Note, the image requirements are as follows and should be included in the Meta post:

> #### Image requirements
>
> - The image that you create must be **300 x 250 pixels**, or double that if high DPI.
> - Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
> - Must be GIF or PNG
> - No animated GIFs
> - Absolute limit on file size of **150 KB**
> - **If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.**

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was fishing for. I spend a chunk of time on Meta.SE looking for information but was coming up dry.

Comment: I nominate @CreationEdge to design a community ad for A&C!

Comment: I'd love to see a community ad on Graphic Design! You'd have my upvote

Comment: Was an ad ever made? Is it still useful?