# Let's advertise the community on some related sites!

Tags: discussion, advertising

It's getting a bit quiet here and we'd like to up our visibility a bit.

We think a good start for that is to create some directed Community Ads on other sites (as was discussed previously [here](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189/what-can-we-do-to-advertise-between-se-sites-now-that-we-are-in-public-beta)).

This post is a place for anyone interested in creating an ad for another site to post it for review before we submit it to the target site. It's really important that we make a good impression with these because we have to convince the users of the target sites that this ad is worthy of being there.

There are a few rules for these ads:

> #### Image requirements
>
> - The image that you create must be **300 x 250 pixels**, or double that if high DPI.
> - Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
> - Must be GIF or PNG
> - No animated GIFs
> - Absolute limit on file size of **150 KB**
> - **If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.**

These can **only** be posted on "graduated" sites, so we won't be able to advertise on Beta sites like Woodworking.

#### Here are some sites I think would be good targets for us:

- Graphic Design
- Photography
- Science Fiction & Fantasy
- Anime

Note, these ads should be specific to the site. We don't want to spam one generic ad to all sites. So, for Anime, perhaps it reads something like "Need help drawing your own manga?".

If you have other ideas for good target sites, feel free to comment or edit.

Comment: RPG and Arqade might be good candidates as well.

Comment: Blender, 3D Printing, and Computer Graphics are not-so-good but potential candidates.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Something in this vein for RPG & Arqade, possibly SFF.

Comment: IANAGD (Graphic Designer)

Comment: What font is that?

Comment: @Matt http://www.dafont.com/potsdam.font?text=CRAFTS.SE

Comment: @CreationEdge That's actually very hard to believe...

Answer (score 5):

This Doctor Who themed ad has been accepted on [scifi.se] for the rest of the year.

[image]

Comment: Very nice! Rand showed me earlier.